# Unable to insert data into partitioned table using Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm new to Databricks .I'm trying to insert data into partitioned table using Databricks with below syntax. But no luck.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FireDept;

CREATE TABLE FireDept (CallNumber INT, UnitID STRING, IncidentNumber INT, 
CallType STRING,     CallDate STRING,  WatchDate STRING,       
 ReceivedDtTm STRING,       
 EntryDtTm STRING,       
 DispatchDtTm STRING,       
 ResponseDtTm STRING,       
 OnSceneDtTm STRING,       
 TransportDtTm STRING,                  
 HospitalDtTm STRING,       
 CallFinalDisposition STRING,       
 AvailableDtTm STRING,       
 Address STRING,       
 City STRING,       
 ZipcodeofIncident INT,       
 Battalion STRING,                 
 StationArea STRING,       
 Box STRING,       
 OriginalPriority STRING,       
 Priority STRING,       
 FinalPriority INT,       
 ALSUnit BOOLEAN,       
 CallTypeGroup STRING,
 NumberofAlarms INT,
 UnitType STRING,
 Unitsequenceincalldispatch INT,
 FirePreventionDistrict STRING,
 SupervisorDistrict STRING,
 NeighborhoodDistrict STRING,
 Location STRING,
 RowID STRING)
USING csv
OPTIONS (header "true")
PARTITIONED BY (CallType)
LOCATION '/mnt/Databricks/employee/Fire_Department_Calls_for_Service.csv';
```

RESULT is showing : OK

--===========

```
%sql

select * from FireDept
```

RESULT is showing : OK

What is wrong in above statements? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, in the Create table DDL it says OK because the table is created. When you do a select it says OK because the table is empty. Insert something into the table and do a select * from FireDept and you'll see the result.

When you insert into the table, you don't specify the column names as you do in some SQL dialects.

If you're trying to create a table from some csv file in DataBricks, I suggest you try the following:

```
%scala 
val data_from_csv = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/mnt/Databricks/employee/Fire_Department_Calls_for_Service.csv") 

data_from_csv.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("events")
```

Please note that I haven't try this code, but the solution is this.

Comment: Hi Stefan,

Thank you so much for reply.

Yes,I was trying to insert data into "FireDept" table using below insert command. But no luck.

Insert cmd:-

LOAD DATA is not supported for datasource tables: `default`.`firedept`;

Error:
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: LOAD DATA is not supported for datasource tables: `default`.`firedept`;

As suggested,Is this only the way to insert data from CSV file to DataBricks table?